# Unable to Run Boot Camp Assistant Because of Microsoft Reserved Partition in disk0s2

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

I keep running into this error when running Boot Camp Assistant:

> Boot Camp Assistant was unable to verify if the Windows partition
> contains a Windows installation. This may be because BitLocker is
> enabled on the partition. If so, disable BitLocker on the disk
> before removing Boot Camp.

Here is my `diskutil list` output:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         249.7 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +249.7 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume Mac OS - Data           19.9 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 30.1 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                525.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Mac OS                  11.1 GB    disk1s5
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the Microsoft Reserved partition by entering the command given below.

```
diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s2
```

Restarting the Mac afterwards would probably be a good idea.

> Note: When installing a UEFI booting Windows, Microsoft states there needs to be a Microsoft Reserved partition. However, I have never seen the Boot Camp Assistant create this partition when employed to install Windows.